# xCode 8, Swift 3.0 -> Invalid Binary

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, xcode8

Few days ago, i received an "Invalid Binary" when i was trying to update one of my apps, reading this forum realize that many people are facing the same problem. One of them could solve it by downgrading the xcode to version 7 and i wanna try this after try other possible solutions..

i am wondering... Swift 3 can work with xcode 7 or Swift 3 is only for xcode 8?

xcode recommended me to migrate mi app ( swift 2.3 ) to swift 3, and i did it, so now my app is in Swift 3 but what is gonna happend if i downgrade to xcode 7 ?

does my app run ok ?

Thanks in advance..

xcode 8
swift 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be caused if your version number and/or build number is incorrect. I've had it happen before.

Comment: @JuanCarlosSalinasOjeda Oh, I see your problem. I think your build number should be different than your version number, at least that's how I've understood it. I don't think build numbers can have periods in them either.

Comment: In my first version of an app I put the build number at 1. Each time I submit a new version, I increase the build number by one. Also, the version number must increase by one. So version 1.1 succeeds version 1.0, or version 1.1.1 succeeds 1.0. This is how version and build numbers work.

Comment: Those are just a bunch of things that might be causing the problem. iTunes Connect should have sent you an email explaining why your build is a rejected binary after they rejected it. Take a look at that email and that might help.

Comment: Thanks @Nathanael, but that's the problem, i receive no email!

Comment: Hmmm, well, if you go into My Apps in iTunesConnect (requires you to be part of the Apple Developer program) you should be able to find out there. Also, try some of the suggestions I mentioned, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: No problem! Hope you fix it.

Comment: Thanks @Nathanael, i change the build version for 106 instead of 1.0.6 and that make the magic! my app is now "Waiting for review", thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 will not work with Xcode 7. Definitely edit your build number as @Nathanael said.

If you didn't get an email- when and how were you warned of the Invalid Binary? Screenshot and attach it.

Comment: He was probably warned about the invalid binary through the iTunes Connect app. The app sends notifications and will let you know if your app has an invalid binary.

Comment: yeap.. i receive the notification through the iTunes Connect app.